# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject - Not sure why

Tags: java, gson

I have the following code:

```
    JsonElement deviceConfig = null;

    JsonObject status = getRestAPI().Connectivity().getDeviceStatus(device);

    deviceConfig = status.get("deviceConfig");

    if (deviceConfig == null || deviceConfig.isJsonNull()) {
        deviceConfig = status.get("mConfig");
    }

    if (deviceConfig != null && !deviceConfig.isJsonNull()) {
        if (!deviceConfig.getAsString().isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

For some reasons, I get the following error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
>           at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)

In this line:

```
if (!deviceConfig.getAsString().isEmpty()) {
```

Any idea why I get this exception although I checked that the JSON is not null?

Comment: it means that getAsString() for that class is not implemented

Comment: @Stultuske How is it possible, I see it is implemented for GSON `JsonElement`

Comment: yes, and all the implementation does, is throw that Exception: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java

Comment: Assuming deviceConfig is a json object, Is it legit to do `deviceConfig.getAsJsonObject.toString()` to fix this issue?

Comment: It might. I don't know what exactly you expect as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonElement Source code: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java

The JsonElement class is an abstract class, it's meant to be used through subclasses that provide further implementations, for which the abstract class isn't concrete enough.

The getAsString method exists, yes, but is implemented like this:

```
  /**
   * convenience method to get this element as a string value.
   *
   * @return get this element as a string value.
   * @throws ClassCastException if the element is of not a {@link JsonPrimitive} and is not a valid
   * string value.
   * @throws IllegalStateException if the element is of the type {@link JsonArray} but contains
   * more than a single element.
   */
  public String getAsString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
```

Which basically means: you are expected to provide an implementation in your subclass.

So, in order to get the result you desire, you'll need to cast the variable to your subclass before calling getAsString() on it.

Comment: Why does the documentation say it throws
ClassCastException or IllegalStateException
and not that it throws the UnsupportedOperationException that can only be seen in the implementation. seems a bit confusing to me.
Is it because the other 2 Exceptions can occur when trying to throw the UnsupportedOperationException ?